# lowlevel_refindex: Best practises?

Tags: typo3, command-line-interface

In the admin tools in the BE, the check or update of the reference index can  be found under "DB Check". For larger installations, the script is started via command line (CLI) so that the execution time does not matter.

My questions:

- Does updating the refindex make any sense or is it really necessary?
- How often should it happen?
- How do you prevent parallel execution if the previous lowlevel_refindex process is still working?
- Are there somewhere best practices to read?

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a valid question. Though old, I will try to answer.

### When you should run it

What I would recommend:

1. Doing it on the command line (cli) is generally a good practice.
2. You can let it run automatically, e.g. once a day.

It should definitely be run *before* you do a major update or *before* you run the lowlevel cleaner.

### What it is used for

To answer your question "is it really necessary".

The reference index contains references between records. For example, if you add an image to a content element, the reference index is updated with a record containing information about the reference between the content element and the image (additionally to the table *sys_file_reference* used to maintain the associated files).

This is for example used to show the number of references that an element (in this case the image) has, which may trigger a warning when you try to delete it.

[image]

If you empty your reference index (which I would not really recommend in production, but you can do it on a test system):

```
mysql>truncate sys_refindex;
```

these references will not be shown (until you update the refindex again):

[image]

### Why is the reference index not up to date?

That is something you did not ask but I have been asking myself: In my test case (adding an image to a content element) it was updated automatically. I am just assuming, there may be core functionality / extensions that do not properly update the reference index when they make changes. Otherwise this would not really be necessary.

It's probably best to just do it (update it regularly).

Comment: Thanks so far.

"Why is the reference index not up to date?" is a good point: if the index would be updated, my question "is updating the refindex really necessary?" would be obsolete.

Sure, we can update the refindex regularly. But i is it really **necessary**? For small instances, we shouldn't worry and just do it. But big instances with **many** relations? Should the updater run daily about an hour producing some load - and that just because it _might_ be useful or there _might_ be inconsistencies?

Comment: @Julian That is a good question which I don't have an answer to right now. I think it would be a good idea to look into this for the latest versions.